# Any good links to learn the maths behind AES?

Tags: aes, resources

I'm creating an academic poster for my EPQ on the mathematics of cryptography.  I would like to do a section on AES, however, I am struggling to find good resources to understand the maths.  I have watched the [computerphile](https://youtu.be/O4xNJsjtN6E) video on AES but it doesn't explain that much of the maths.  Is there any good resources out there that is able to explain the maths behind it in a not too complicated way so I am able to simplify the maths down so a sixth-former can understand it.

Comment: On the [http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html](A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)) website.  In Act 3 the key expansion part 1, some of the cells have letters and others have just numbers.  I don't fully understand why that is the case.  I understand it comes from the substitutions, however, some of the letters change back to numbers but others stay.  Why is this the case?  Edit: Don't know how the links work

Comment: Characters represent the plaintext, instead of hex coding, they chose to characters. After the first x-or they chose hex.

Comment: If you do not have knowledge of finite field arithmetic, as well as knowledge of binary and hexadecimal encoding and bitwise logical operations, you need to start there first

Comment: You could also give a look to this paper: https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2002/24420001/24420001.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Lenstra's short document *Rijndael for Algebraists* is fantastic to get started on the maths behind AES:

https://math.berkeley.edu/~hwl/papers/rijndael0.pdf

You can find some information on finite fields [on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) have a look at the example of $GF(4)$.

For a detailed overview of the cipher see the book  [The Design of Rijndael:The AES Standard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540425802) by its designers.

There is also [The Stick Figure Guide to AES](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html), at a more informal and descriptive level.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that The Design of Rijndael can be difficult to read if you aren't already familiar with topics such as linear/differential cryptanalysis.